# Incorrect Nimbus host resolution

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, apache-storm

I am running Apache Storm Nimbus and Supervisor inside separate docker containers, using https://hub.docker.com/_/storm/. The containers are running on the same AWS EC2 instance.
The command I am using to start the Nimbus Container is

```
docker run -p 6627:6627 --hostname <ec2_public_ip> -d --restart always --name nimbus storm storm nimbus -c storm.zookeeper.servers='[<zookeeper_hosts>]'
```

The command I am using to start the Supervisor Container is

```
docker run -p 6700:6700 --hostname <ec2_public_ip> -d --restart always --name supervisor storm storm supervisor -c storm.zookeeper.servers='[<zookeeper_hosts>]' -c nimbus.seeds='[<ec2_public_ip>]'
```

All the ports are open in the security group and the zookeeper instances are up and running.

When I try to deploy a topology from my local box using

```
storm jar topology.jar topologyClass
```

Storm initially uses the correct public ip address and logs

```
2037 [main] INFO  o.a.s.u.NimbusClient - Found leader nimbus : ip-<private_ip_address>.us-west-1.compute.internal:6627
```

However, you can see that in the above log the private ip address is returns, to which storm is not able to connect.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-<private_ip_address>.us-west-1.compute.internal
```

Can someone please point out what would be the approach for the public ip address to be sent back to Storm from inside the docker container instead of the private ip address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nimbus figures out its hostname/port in https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/e909b3d604367e7c47c3bbf3ec8e7f6b672ff778/storm-client/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/nimbus/NimbusInfo.java#L56

As you can see, you should set `storm.local.hostname` in your storm.yaml.

Comment: Thanks. This has fixed it.